# Vertex grips (dots) are missing in vertex edit mode. How do I get them back?

Tags: modeling

I'm newish to Blender, new to blender 2.8. My objects, in edit mode, do not have vertex grips(dots) when in vertex edit mode. I've increased the vertex pixel resolution from 3 to 6 in the Theme 3D view settings. I've ensured that overlays is on. I've reloaded default view port settings. I've uninstalled and reinstalled and still have the same issue. Its not always a problem but it does make it difficult to choose vertices when modeling. any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? If you have vertex select enabled in edit mode, the vertices should be displayed

Comment: Have you tried loading the factory settings? Sometimes even new installs use your old settings.

Comment: Am I crazy or am I seeing vertex dots in the screenshot?

Comment: I've not only loaded factory settings but I've also deleted the config file in the appdata 2.8 folder to force blender into creating a clean startup config file upon startup. I can assure you that there is no vertex grip in the screenshot. The vertex point of intersection is highlighted when clicked but there is no dot. Additionally this is vertex edit mode so all visible vertex intersections should have a dot

Comment: @Millard I think ur crazy haha I didnt see any

Comment: no, I'm just blind.  I looked at it more closely and there are no dots.  Really, this won't stop anyone from being able to model, it's just annoying.

Comment: there seems to be a lot of people having weird problems with 2.80, just no one else seems to have their problems.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look everyone. @Millard, your right it is annoying but I can still model. So its either back to 2.79 or suck it up and see how far I can get with the bug. If I do run across a fix I'll be sure to post.

Comment: I suggest you stick to 2.80.  The benefits outway the costs.  I assume you know about all it's cool features?

Comment: Im learning ;-)